# Python Turtle Graphics (Not Responding) in Spyder 4.2.0

Tags: spyder

I typed the code lines below in Spyder 4.2.0 editor (I'm using window 10 and Python 3.7)

from turtle import Turtle

name = Turtle()

print('str')

I expect the Python Turtle Graphics window opened and actives, but it is not. The message indicates: Python Turtle Graphics Not Responding.  Can anyone know why? Please share. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use

```
import turtle

a = turtle.Turtle()
a.write('sample text')
turtle.done()
```

Here, I made turtle named a write sample text.

Make sure to use command turtle.done() on the end of the script.

To read more about writing text with turtle, go to [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turtle-write-function-in-python/)

I wish you luck with programming.